# Drupal 8: Mismatched entity and/or field definitions

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, pathauto

While trying to understand why my view is not displaying, I noticed the following error in the log:

[image]

I do not think it is possible to delete the URL alias from Taxonomy terms. At least I cannot find how to do this. 
I have, however gone through ALL of my taxonomy terms and removed the value for this field.

I have also done the following with Pathauto:
[image]

Also, I have checked the report located at admin/reports/fields and can confirm that there are no entities that use a field called URL alias.

I have gone through each content item and ensured that they have the following setting (anyone know how to do this in bulk?). But still the error remains.
[image]

Anyone know then how I can fix this strange error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not entirely sure what this command does, but it fixed the error:

```
drush updb --entity-updates
```

Answer (score 0):

Since https://www.drupal.org/node/2554097, the magic in Drupal core that took care of updating entity definitions is gone. `drush updb --entiy-updates` is an alternative to this but it is not a silver bullet. Instead, it is safer to write database updates.

Taking the screenshot at the top as an example, here is a database update that would delete those two field definitions:

```
/**
 * Fix taxonomy and node field definitions.
 *
 */
function mymodule_update_8101() {
  $manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();

  if ($field = $manager->getFieldStorageDefinition('alias', 'node')) {
    $manager->uninstallFieldStorageDefinition($field);
  }

  if ($field = $manager->getFieldStorageDefinition('alias', 'term')) {
    $manager->uninstallFieldStorageDefinition($field);
  }
}
```

Have a look at the rest of the available methods at https://www.drupal.org/node/2554097 in order to write database updates for each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

use the entity_update module or the devel_entity_updates module